# How to mask CCSprite with bezier path

Tags: path, cocos2d-iphone, mask, bezier

I want to mask a CCSprite in my training project with bezier path - make a path programmatically and use it as a mask on CCSprite's image. I googled a lot but I only found tutorials for simple masking (image - image), not shapes and paths.
Any tutorials or approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you explain what you mean with "using a path as a mask"? Can you add some images to illustrate what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: well, I'd like to do a little puzzle game, I have a bezier path of a jigsaw piece and I want to use that path to mask a piece of an image :) I have to use bezier path, because the jigsaw pieces are not always the same, if you know what I mean

Comment: I know how to do that with UIBezierPath and UIImage, but have no clue how to achieve this in cocoa2d

Comment: unfortunately I am not familiar enough to cocos2d to help out on this question.

Comment: Thank you anyway for trying, perhaps somebody else will know